# Finding a subtree in a CakePHP Tree

Tags: php, cakephp, tree, mptt

In CakePHP, how do you select just a subtree in a model which `actsAs` tree?

I tried this, to find the tree headed by the item with `label = "My Label"`

```
$this->find("threaded", array(
    "conditions" => array(
        "label" => "My Label"
    )
));
```

...however looking at the logs, it runs this SQL:

```
SELECT Menu.id, Menu.parent_id, Menu.lft, Menu.rght, Menu.label, Menu.link
FROM menus Menu
WHERE label = 'My Label'
```

Which obviously only selects the one node, and not all its children.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you will have to do it in two steps like this (from [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/812/find-threaded)):

```
$parent = $this->Category->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('label' => 'My label')
));
$parentAndChildren = $this->Category->find('threaded', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Category.lft >=' => $parent['Category']['lft'], 
        'Category.rght <=' => $parent['Category']['rght']
    )
));
```

You can't use the `'label' => 'my label'` condition in the `threaded` call, since it would only find results that match that condition, parents and children. `'threaded'` only rearranges the results of a normal find operation based on the `parent_id`, so you'll have to supply your own condition of what "children" are by using the `lft`/`rght` columns.

Comment: yeah I ended up doing pretty much exactly this same thing - it seems funny to not have included this functionality in the component.

Comment: I agree, seems like an obvious use case. There's `->children()` but no `->childrenThreaded()`. Poking around the model class I'm thinking you could probably do `$model->_findThreaded('after', null, $model->children($id))` if you're going by id, but it seems kinda hacky. :o)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also hoped for a way that is more concise than this. By the way, if you only want the children you should use `'conditions' => array('Category.lft >' => $parent['Category']['lft'], 'Category.rght <' => $parent['Category']['rght'])` to not fetch the parent again.

Comment: Hi, how do I display it to my view? How do I loop if I have 10 level of children...